# how to reduce waiting time asp.net mvc on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just started to coding ASP.NET MVC. Every single time after I save the code refreshing browser takes 4-5 seconds.

is there any solution for this issue?

[image: problem ss]

Comment: I wish I could refresh in just 4-5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

No, this is the time needed to recompile the code and get the latest version. Lucky you, before this version we had to stop the execution and run it again in order to get the latest version.

Comment: If I use "build solution", after this refreshing browser manually. it's still takes 4-5 seconds to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The wait time is caused by building the changed `.cshtml` file(s). Behind the scenes a C# class is generated and compiled for every `.cshtml` file, and this needs to be redone after every change.
That is also why you can see changes to your `.cshtml` while your site is running, without having to rebuild the Solution.

By default this on-the-fly build step is not included in the Visual Studio action "Build Solution" (Ctrl-Shift-B).
You can however force it to do so by manually editing the MVC `.csproj` file to contain `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`, but note that doing so will dramatically increase the time spent by Ctrl-Shift-B.

More info (and also how to do it for a Build Server):
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx/

Answer (score -3):

Sure, Node.js® is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient. More information on Node.js can be found here: https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: thank you but irrelevant, I have to start a project with asp.net mvc :(